# Python 3 and Django: write Georgian text to PDF file

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, pdf-generation, xhtml2pdf

The problem was to write Georgian text to PDF file. I have tried several encodings, however, this didn't solve the problem. Also  I tryd to use some fonts, but it hasnot any result. I need help..
i use xhtml2pdf modul

```
def customer_render_pdf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
      pk = kwargs.get('pk')
      customer = get_object_or_404(id, pk=pk)  
      template_path = 'test.html'
      context = {'customer': customer}
      response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
      response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename= "report.pdf"'
      template = get_template(template_path)
      html = template.render(context)
      pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF( html, 
                    dest=response,
                    encoding='utf-8'
       )
      return response
```

2. html code, i am using some css fonts i html page :

@media print {

```
@font-face {
    font-family: DIN;
    src: url(font/rina.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: DejaMono;
    src: url(font/DejaVuSansMono.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: DejaMono;
    src: url(font/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf);
    font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: DejaMono;
    src: url(font/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf);
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: DejaMono;
    src: url(font/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: DINL;
    src: url(font/DINLt___.afm);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: DINL;
    src: url(font/DINMd___.afm);
    font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: DejaSans;
    src: url(font/DejaVuSans.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: code2000;
    src: url("font/CODE2000.TTF");
}
```

}

Comment: A few things that could help people provide feedback: Please include `test.html`. What encodings have you attempted to use? Is Python throwing any errors? If the PDF is being created at all, what does it look like?

Comment: {%load static%}
<html lang="en">
    <pdf:language name="Georgia"/>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8", encode="utf-8", http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html";>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
                Detail Report PDF  
                <p style=" font-family:HYGothic-Medium">sdasdsd ადსდ ჯმ ფკნ ნფ,ფს Как 如何 სნddsd</p>

            </div>

Comment: it is part of my html page